# Unity resolve exception

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I'm trying to execute the following in my Unit Test:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
var test = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnityContainer>();
```

I get the following error, not sure what's going on:

> 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unity.Mvc5.dll but was not
>   handled in user code

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Seems odd to resolve IUnityContainer

Comment: I'm trying to use container to get a service